# Can I use String variable instead of int in abstract class

Tags: java

First off all sorry for my English.

I have to do practice for class with Java. I'm completely beginner level at Java.

I'm trying to do Caesar Cipher. My Caesar cipher must override an abstract `Cipher` class.

This is my abstract `Cipher` class.

```
abstract class Cipher {  
    abstract String encode(String input, String keyword );
    abstract String decode(String input, String keyword );
}
```

And this is my Caesar cipher.

```java
public class Ceaser extends Cipher {

    String encode(String input, String keyword) {
        String encodedMessage = "";
        for (char e:input.toCharArray()) {
            if (e+keyword > 122) {
                e = (char) ('A' + (e+keyword-123));
            } else {
                e+=keyword;
            }
            encodedMessage+=e;
        }
        return encodedMessage;
    }

    String decode(String input, String keyword) {
        String decodedMessage = "";
        for (char e:input.toCharArray()) {
            if (e-keyword<65) {
                int a = e-keyword;
                int b = 65-a;
                e = (char) ('z' - b+1);
            } else {
                e-=keyword;
            }
            decodedMessage+=e;
        }
        return decodedMessage;
    }
}
```

In the Caesar cipher, the `keyword` variable must be `int`. But I have to override the abstract class which is `String`. I'm thinking about using length of string as a integer. But I couldn't do it. How can I do?

Comment: Just pass in a number as a String value and then use `Integer.parseInt(keyword)` to turn the string value into an integer.

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(keyword);`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass number as a string in the method like this,

```
decode("text", "200")
```

And inside the method you can convert this string into an integer like this,

```
int i =  Integer.parseInt("200")
```

It will return 200 as an integer.